# python package, prevent sdist from adding dev-r0 to a package name

Tags: setuptools, distutils, python-packaging

I own a python package called `webpreview` which extracts information from a webpage reading its meta data and contents. Its initial release was versioned `1.0.0`.

I used `python setup.py sdist` to package it. From its initial release sdist would append `dev` to the package name. So the package would be named `webpreview-1.0.0dev.tar.gz` instead of `webpreview-1.0.0.tar.gz`.

Today I tested it against python `3.3` and tried to deploy it. This time sdist names it `webpreview-1.0.3dev-r0.tar.gz` making it impossible to release it to pypi.

How can I remove the `dev, rc` stuff from the package name?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you just have to set the `version` parameter in `setup()`, and `distutils` will build the correct package name ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data)) - so if its `1.0.0`, it will make an `webpreview-1.0.0.tar.gz` unless your setup.py or your build enviroment contains any unmentioned extensions to distutils.

EDIT: I just downloaded your source and everthing went as expected. You forgot to mention there is a `setup.cfg`, which has a section containing:

```
[egg_info]
tag_build = dev
tag_svn_revision = true
```

remove this file and voila! no more `dev`-tag

Comment: the version is 1.0.3 you could check the source here. https://github.com/ludbek/webpreview